# Swift 4 generic, referencing self

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, subclass, self

I'm considering the following structure using Swift 4:

```
class BaseClass {

    // abstract function
    func doSomething<T: BaseClass>(with object: T) {}

}

class SubClass: BaseClass {

    var title: String = "hello world"

    // implementation
    override func doSomething<T: BaseClass>(with object: T) {
        // do something with object
        // can I access object.title here?
    }

}
```

In the above snippet the `object.title` property is not accessible, because apparently type of `object` property is `BaseClass`, not `SubClass`.

I assume the function parameter type should be set as `Self`, such as:

```
func doSomething(with object: Self) {}
```

but the following error occurs while compilation.

`'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class; did you mean 'BaseClass'?`

Is there a way to reference type of self while overriding functions from base class?

#### Edit

So my question is whether we can access `SubClass`'s properties inside functions that overrides super class's functions (as `object.title` property is in `SubClass` implementation). I was considering a whole lot of classes that inherit base class, so I thought it might be useful to have functions that interacts with another instance with the same type when called.

Comment: I think you cannot access the subclass property on baseclass object, you can access `title` like this `self.title` inside `doSomething`

Comment: You cannot have covariance like that with a function parameter. Consider if it were possible; `BaseClass` would say that you can pass in an instance of a type that inherits from, or is, `BaseClass`. `SubClass` would then say that you can actually *only* pass in an instance of a type that inherits from, or is, `SubClass`. That's a clear violation of the Liskov substitution principle, you could upcast a `SubClass` to a `BaseClass` and then pass in a `BaseClass` argument to a method that's expecting the instance to conform to `SubClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a function kike `func doSomething(with object: Self) {}` since it would mean different things in those classes (and thus, would not overwrite each other semantically)

Think about calling the subclass with a `BaseClass` object, that is not a `Subclass`, if you had a method with `Self` like you showed in your snippet, it would be implemented by the supperclass, but the subclass would not implement it anymore.

But, you can cast it like this in the subclass:

```
override func doSomething<T: BaseClass>(with object: T) {
    guard let subClass = object as? SubClass else { return }
    print("\(title): \(subClass.title)")
}
```